# Why is it when I changed my primary e-mail address on Facebook I didn't need to log back in on my phone?

Tags: facebook, email

I changed the e-mail address I use to log into Facebook but I didn't have to change it on my phone (until I logged out and logged back in). Does Facebook keep a record of past log in credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon successful login, many sites, including Facebook, store authentication cookies on your browser, which explains why you were able to keep using FB on your phone until you logged out and attempted to log in again.